# How to make Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider reach an AKS deployed endpoint (publically accessible only using VPN)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-aks, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure B2C custom policy that uses the Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider in order to enhance the Reset Password flow.

I have no issue if the Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider endpoint is public.
But for the production, my endpoint ( a spring boot app) will be running on an AKS cluster and its URL will be only accessible through a VPN connection which makes my endpoint invisible for my Azure B2C custom policy.

The question is: How can I make my Custom policy reach an endpoint deployed on AKS and accessible only using VPN?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C API Connectors (Including the [Restful Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile)) publicly accessible HTTPS APIs and endpoints. It's not possible to connect to APIs trough VPNs.